# Runtime function branching on compile-time function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, runtime, metaprogramming

Consider a compile-time function of the form:

```
template <unsigned int Value>
constexpr unsigned int function() 
{
    // Just for the example, but it could be very complicated here
    return Value*Value;
}
```

How to write the runtime equivalent that will call the right compile-time version using template metaprogramming, knowing that the `value` will always be in the `[From, To[` interval:

```
template <unsigned int From, unsigned int To, /* Something here */>
constexpr unsigned int function(const unsigned int value)
{
    // Something here
}
```

The branching to the right version should be as fast as possible.

For example `function<0, 32>(6)` (runtime version) should call `function<6>()` (compile-time version).

EDIT: Explanation:
Why do I want to do this? This function (real use case) need to be as fast as possible (supercomputing issues). By providing the parameter at compile-time, I can generate very efficient code. If I simply move the value from the template parameter to a function parameter, the code is between 10 and 100 times slower. But in fact, this parameter does not have a very wide range of possible values (like between `0` and `32`): so it would be far more efficient to branch at runtime on the right compile-time version.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you add an example?

Comment: Does the provided example clarify the question?

Comment: If `x` is not known at compile-time, you will not know the value of `function<0, 255>(x)` at compile-time. What is your goal?

Comment: @PaulDraper: I think he's (effectively) asking how to generate a jump table, so `function<0, 255>(x)` will have the equivalent of `switch (x) { case 0: return function<0>(); case 1: return function<1>(); /* etc*/ default: throw "nope"; }`. I've asked a similar question in the past. You can do this with recursion and then rely on the compiler to unroll it. (The point being that your program can generate the result of `function<N>` at compile-time, and you can poke into those results.)

Comment: @PaulDraper I've added the explanation.

Comment: Oh I understand. One (simple) solution is to create an array from `0` to `255` and then index into that. But I suppose you want something more elegant involving templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to set up a recursive cascading `if`/`recurse` chain.

```
#define RETURNS(X) -> decltype(X) { return (X); }

template<unsigned From, unsigned To, typename Target>
struct CallIf {
  constexpr auto operator()( unsigned N )
    RETURNS( (N==From)?Target::template func<From>():CallIf<From+1, To, Target>()( N ) );
};
template<unsigned From, typename Target>
struct CallIf<From, From+1, Target> {
  constexpr auto operator()( unsigned N )
    RETURNS( Target::template func<From>() );
};

struct Func {
  template<unsigned V>
  constexpr unsigned func() const {
    return function<V>();
  }
};
```

or something like that, and rely on the compiler collapsing that chain of `if`s down to one.  (if you know the return type, you can do away with that annoying `RETURNS` macro, or if you have C++1y features you can do the same).

Now, you might want to compare this to a version that does a binary search on `value` in that range, using a similar recursive call case.  Similarly, you could do it by checking and setting bits in a compile time value.

```
template<unsigned From, unsigned To, typename Target>
struct CallIf {
  enum { Mid = From + (To-From)/2 }; // avoid overflow risk
  constexpr auto operator()( unsigned N )
    RETURNS( (N>=Mid)?CallIf<Mid, To, Target>()(N):CallIf<From,Mid,Target>()(N) );
};
```

with the same specialization for the 1-width case.

Another approach would be to set up a `static` array of invocations of `function<V>` and then do an array dereference at run time:

```
template<unsigned...> struct indexes {};
template<unsigned Min, unsigned Max, unsigned... Is> struct make_indexes:make_indexes<Min, Max-1, Max-1, Is...> {};
template<unsigned Min, unsigned... Is> struct make_indexes<Min, Min, Is...>:indexes<Is...> {};

template<unsigned From, unsigned To, typename Target>
struct CallIf {
  template<unsigned... Is>
  unsigned Invoke( indexes<Is...>, unsigned N ) const {
    typedef unsigned(*target)();
    static target ts[] = { &(function<Is>)... };
    return ts[N-From]();
  };
  unsigned operator()( unsigned N ) const {
    return Invoke( make_indexes<From, To>(), N );
  }
};
```

although I'm not sure how to make the above `constexpr` easily in C++11 at least, and I skipped out on doing return-type deduction.

None of the above are tested or compiled, so most likely will require some repair.  But the core concept will work.  The specialization might need some work: doing `<From, From+1` to terminate is something I haven't done in practice: if that causes issues, you can do `<From, Width` based helper, and specialize on `Width=1`.

I personally call this technique (embodied in the `CallIf` type above) the "magic switch", where we take a run time valid and "magically" make it a compile time value.  I only mention this because you can probably find me talking about it on stack overflow by googling Yakk and "magic switch" (and site:stackoverflow.com) for other variations, some of which have been compiled and have live examples attached.

Finally, while the last version (the manual jump table) may be fastest, if you are calling it so often that the speed of this invocation is key, you might want to think about wrapping not just the call site, but the algorithm surrounding it in a magic switch: do the dispatching earlier.  If, however, you only get the index at the last moment, and you are ok with a non-`constexpr` call, it should work.  Note that `static` arrays will be created for each `Function` and `To` and `From` used.

Answer (score 0):

You may create an (`constexpr`) array of results, something like :

```
#if 1 // Not in C++11

template <std::size_t ...> struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t ...Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence < I - 1, I - 1, Is... > {};

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> {};

#endif

template <unsigned int Value>
constexpr unsigned int function()
{
    // Just for the example, but it could be very complicated here
    return Value * Value;
}

namespace detail
{
    template <std::size_t From, std::size_t...Is>
    struct result_array
    {
        static constexpr std::array<unsigned int, sizeof...(Is)> values = {{::function<From + Is>()...}};
    };

    template <std::size_t From, std::size_t...Is>
    constexpr std::array<unsigned int, sizeof...(Is)> result_array<From, Is...>::values;

    template <std::size_t From, std::size_t...Is>
    constexpr unsigned int function(unsigned int value, index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return result_array<From, Is...>::values[value - From];
    }
} // namespace detail

template <unsigned int From, unsigned int To>
constexpr unsigned int function(const unsigned int value)
{
    static_assert(From < To, "Invalid template parameters");
    return detail::function<From>(value, make_index_sequence<std::size_t(To + 1 - From)>());
}
```